# Instagram - blocked account due to community guidelines (hacked) - with Facebook login - how to recover account?

Tags: facebook, security, instagram, hacked

This sounds like a mouthful but let me explain.

- The Instagram account was used with Facebook login.
- Someone logged into the account (Instagram) and posted something that was against the guidelines.
- Instagram tells you, that you can request a review at this point to get it unblocked.
- But since Facebook login was used, I am not presented with the review option.

It goes like this:

1. I open Instagram.
2. I tap Login with Facebook.
3. I enter my Facebook details.
4. It tells me, my Facebook account was blocked, because it was connected to the Instagram account.

And that's it. There is no support center, there is no support form, ask for review, anything. Because of the Instagram account, the Facebook is now limited too (I can't even manage the business page I have), and thus, the whole thing is stuck.

It seems like it's just a huge flaw / issue on META's side: First of all, they shouldn't block an entire Facebook account, just because the Instagram account didn't meet Guidelines. Even then, it should allow me to go to Instagram and submit a review request.

But I'm sure there is some other way around this. I tried all kinds of options on the Facebook/Instagram help center page, but no luck.

Comment: [Wired 2019-Aug](https://www.wired.com/story/instagram-unlink-account-wont-unlink-facebook/): *Because Facebook and Instagram share infrastructure, systems, and technology, we connect information about your activities across our services based on a variety of signals,”... ...“Linking or unlinking your accounts in the app doesn’t affect this.”*

Comment: I mean, I am fine with them being linked. But this whole lock on the Facebook account prevents me from going through the Request Review process - if that makes sense. It seems like I don't get the login token from Facebook at all, it just puts me to a page where I can download data, and that's it. It tells me I can contact Instagram's Help. I click that. I go through the process.. and it just throws me back. It's like an infinite loop. :/